# vb.net Form.Enabled vs From.Visible vs Form.Focused

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hopefully an easy question,

I have a thread running in a class that just loops through a bunch of things. I want to stop the thread when the user Closes out of the form. I have the following function in my Form.vb

```
    Public Function getFormStatus() As Boolean
    Dim bAlive As Boolean = False

    If Me.Enabled = True Then
        bAlive = True
    Else
        bAlive = False
    End If

    Return bAlive
End Function
```

Then In my main loop class I have

```
dim isAlive as Boolean = false
isAlive = frm.getFormStatus
while isAlive
   do stuff
```

My problem is I don't know the property of the Form that tells me whether or not it is currently Active! I feel like this shouldn't be difficult but I've tried several different ones and none have given my the expected result.

Comment: Is From.vb the only form in the project, ie. when its closed is the whole application shut down? Or is this just one form in the program? Also, when you say Active, you mean still open, not that it is the current form? Cause your form could still be open but not be the Active one.

Comment: No, this is not the only form of my project, it is an mdi child, and closing out of this form, the mdi parent is still active

Comment: You already asked this question.  You are not getting ahead, whether a form is active has nothing to do with whether it is enabled.  As long as you are in this While loop, nothing is ever going to happen with the form activation state, the UI is completely frozen.  Get rid of the While to get ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread is *active* when it's not completed running what it has been told to run. While that may sound silly, in your above example, you will note that as long as you are in that while loop, the thread is *active*.

If you are looking to perform execution on a seperate thread form the UI thread, I would suggest looking at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) as it will make your approach much cleaner and easier to implement.

With regards to the active form, that can be achieved via the [ActiveForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx) property.

```
Dim currentForm As Form = Form.ActiveForm
```

Comment: You're right, and sorry I misspoke the first time. I don't want the thread to stop, I'm going to have the thread keep running, I just will have a conditional where it skips over all the stuff in the thread when that form isn't active....So I just want to know when the form is active or not, and I see the second thing you posted, when debug and hover over .ActiveForm it shows me 'Nothing' is there a way to return whether or not the form is alive?

Comment: @BrandonJ When you are running in that while loop you will never progress, as all your work is existing on the _same_ thread. Try looking for an event you can register for which will allow you to perform the action when needed.